# How can I read the status (checked or not) of radio buttons in django template

Tags: python, django, templates

How can I read the status (checked or not) of radio buttons in django template. Kindly note that I want to read the status in template itself so that I can display remaining content of template as per the user chosen the choice using radio button. 
context to the template row_list is like this:

```
               col1     col2
  row1        "001"   "XML"
  row2        "002"   "HTML"
  row3        "003"   "DHTML"

     {% for a in row_list %}
      <p>
         {% if forloop.counter < 2 %}
          <input type="radio" name="items" id="choice" value= {{a.col1}} checked />
         {% else %}
           <input type="radio" name="items" id="choice" value ={{a.col1}}   />
        {% endif%}
       {{a.col2}}
    </p>
  {% endfor %}


      {% for r in row_list %}
           {%ifequal r.col1 rb_status %} <!--rb_status may be euqal to"001"/"002"/"003-->
             Subject: <input type="text" name="S_name" value= {{r.col2}}> <br>
          {%endifequal%}  
      {%endfor%}
```

Comment: The template is already rendered when the user gets to see the radio button. If you want to change the page content's on user interaction, this is a client side operation (i.e. JavaScript), Django has already done it's job by that point.

Comment: Django templates are only meant for data presentation, not manipulation. Why can't you use JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Even if I use Javascript to know the status, how can i pass on that status to django template variable rb_status ?

Comment: I need to present the data as per the status of radio button in other part of page...this is very basic requirement of any application

Comment: What if my application requires template to render conditionally and not  via client side as passing context to the java script is at least unknown to me?

Comment: Then it's not a problem, but what you suggested (manipulating HTML markup *after* it is presented to user and user interacted with it) is completely different problem. If you know status of the checkboxes before webpage is rendered, you can perform logic on them, but if you need user to interact with them *first* and *then* manipulate HTML you have to use client side scripts, so please clarify.

Comment: then is the solution like this? rendering page again using view.py knowing the status of radio button using POST/GET url methods. If so, then isn't it the restriction put by django framework?